# Javascript to change innerHTML function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm building an interface that consists of 9 cells in table. When a person mouses over a cell, I want other cells to become visible, and change the text content of some of the cells. I can do that just fine if I create individual functions to change the content of each cell, but that's crazy.

I want a single function to change the text depending on the cells involved. I created a function that can take n arguments, and loops through making changes based on the arguments passed in to the function. It doesn't work.

Code for the function is below. If I call it, `onMouseOver="changebox('div3')"`, the argument makes it to the function when I mouse over the cell. If I uncomment the document.write(cell) statement, in this instance, it prints div3 to the screen. So... why isn't it making any changes to the content of the div3 cell?

```
function changebox() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var cell = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).id;
        var text = "";

        if (cell == 'div3') {
            text = "Reduced Travel";
        } else if (cell == 'div4') {
            text = "Reduced Cost";
        }
        //document.write(cell)
        cell.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've assigned `cell` the value of the `id` attribute. It is not an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `cell` is a string which holds the `id` of the object. Update the code as follows

```
function changebox() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var cell = document.getElementById(arguments[i]),
            text = "";

        if (cell.id == 'div3') {
            text = "Reduced Travel";
        } else if (cell.id == 'div4') {
            text = "Reduced Cost";
        }
        //document.write(cell)
        cell.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**
You can reduce the code as @Tushar suggested.

No need of iterating over `arguments`(*assuming there are only two elements, but can be modified for more elements*).

```
function changebox() {
    // As arguments is not real array, need to use call
    // Check if div is present in the arguments array
    var div3Index = [].indexOf.call(arguments, 'div3') > -1,
        div4Index = [].indexOf.call(arguments, 'div4') > -1;

    // If present then update the innerHTML of it accordingly        
    if (div3Index) {
        document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = 'Reduced Travel';
    } else if (div4Index) {
        document.getElementById('div4').innerHTML = 'Reduced Cost';
    }
}
```

Comment: Also add `function changebox() {  
    var div3Index = [].indexOf.call(arguments, 'div3') > -1,  
        div4Index = [].indexOf.call(arguments, 'div4') > -1;  
    if (div3Index) {  
        document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = 'Reduced Travel';  
    } else if (div4Index) {  
        document.getElementById('div4').innerHTML = 'Reduced Cost';  
    }  
}` in answer. No loop needed. :)

Comment: @SeattleDucati Welcome. Glad to help. :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan in javascript indexOf is not implement by loop through the list? I don't think so. quote from MDN: `indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).
`

Answer (score 1):

```
function changebox() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    args.map(document.getElementById.bind(document)).forEach(setElement);
}

function setElement(ele) {
  if (ele.id === 'div3') {
     ele.innerHTML = "Reduced Travel";
  } else if (ele.id === 'div4') {
     ele.innerHTML = "Reduced Cost";
  }
}
```

this make your function easy to be tested

Answer (score 1):

As your assigning the cell variable the id of the element and changing the innerHTML of cell which is not valid .

```
    var changeText = function() {
    console.log("in change text");
    for(var i= 0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        var cell = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).id;
        var text = "";
        console.log(cell)
        if (cell === "div-1") {
            text = cell+" was selected!!";
        } else if(cell === "div-3") {
            text = cell+" was selected!!";
        } else {
            text = cell+" was selected";
        }

        elem.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

This would properly change the text of div mouseovered!!